# Dynamic attached UILabel is not moving

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have attached a UILabel to view. Now i want to move that label but its not working. here is my code

`UILabel *tick = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];

    CGRect frame = tick.frame;

    frame.origin.x = newVal;

    frame.origin.y = newVal;`


I can change text value of the UILabel tick but how can i move it here and there?

Comment: did u get it working?
i also need to move a uilabel.

Comment: Yes, check out progrmr answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign frame back to tick to change it.

```
tick.frame = frame;
```